# Is duelling legal in Uruguay if both participants are registered blood donors?

Tags: law

I saw the following letter in today's [Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/theguardian/2013/oct/30/laptops-on-the-nhs):

> Having just returned from that country, I note one curious fact you missed about Uruguay (Shortcuts, G2, 23 October): duelling is allowed provided that both parties are registered blood donors.

Is this claim about duelling true?

Comment: Hmmm... According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duel) it was made illegal in Uruguay in 1992 [citation-needed, naturally], but *Paraguay* is the one that is associated with the urban legend.

Comment: The whole history of why dueling became legal in Uruguay (not Paraguay) in 1920 and illegal again in 1992 is the subject of my book: [The Pen, the Sword, and the Law: Dueling and Democracy in Uruguay](https://www.mqup.ca/pen--the-sword--and-the-law--the-products-9780228011026.php) (Montreal: McGill-Queen's University Press, 2022). Apologies for using this thread to promote it, but anyone reading this thread might really be interested.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**NO.**

In 1920, duelling was made legal subject to some strict conditions:

- [New York Times article, 1920](http://query.nytimes.com/mem/archive-free/pdf?res=F60D1EFC355511738DDDAF0894D0405B808EF1D3):

> MONTEVIDEO, Uruguay, Aug 5 — The Chamber of Deputies has approved a bill suppressing existing penalties on duelling, provided certain conditions are fulfilled.
>
> The penalties are suppressed under the bill, provided the seconds submit previously to a court of honor consisting of three members, the question of whether an offense justifying the duel exists and if so who is the offended party.

[Blood banks weren't established until the 1930s](http://www.donateblood.com.au/about-us/history-blood-services/1901-1939), so being a blood donor could not have been a requirement.

While a court of honor met as recently as 1990, **this law was overturned in 1992**.

- [Deseret News article, 1992](http://www.deseretnews.com/article/235374/URUGUAY-RESCINDS-LAW-ALLOWING-DISPUTES-TO-BE-SETTLED-BY-DUEL.html)

> Uruguay's congress has rescinded a 72-year-old law that allowed disputes to be settled by a duel.
>
> [...]
>
> In 1990, police inspector Saul Claveria challenged La Republica newspaper publisher Federico Fasano to a duel over an article that linked Claveria to smuggling.
>
> Claveria eventually withdrew his challenge, saying Fasano was not a worthy opponent.
>
> The lower house approved rescinding the law earlier and the Senate followed suit on Wednesday. It now goes to President Luis Lacalle for signing.

I could find no sign of the law being re-enacted since 1992.